# How do I set the number of tabs and their respective labels in a ViewPager programatically?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, fragment, spinner

Okay, so. I've got a Spinner that has a set of values retrieved from a database. This spinner is inside a Fragment that is a part of a Tabbed Activity that makes use of a ViewPager. This is what I'm trying to acheive:

1. Spinner has a certain value
2. Based on this value, the ViewPager's number of tabs changes (and their respective labels), from information passed from an onChanged() (or simlar) method from the Spinner

Where would I begin in doing this? I am completely clueless on where to start with this.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code in `onResume` to change the number of tabs and pages based on a user selected configuration (specified in my case in another activity). You could call something like this when the user selects a configuration from the spinner.

```
ConfigurationEnum ct = getSelectedConfiguration(); // or pass in from spinner

if( ct != mPagerAdapter.getConfiguration() ) {

    // remove all tabs
    int cnp = mPagerAdapter.getCount();
    while( cnp > 0 ) {
        mPagerAdapter.destroyItem(mViewPager, cnp - 1, mPagerAdapter.getItem(cnp - 1));
        mTabLayout.removeTabAt(cnp-1);
        --cnp;
    }

    // now add back tabs we need
    ArrayList<String> tabList = ct.getTabsToShow();

    for(int i = 0; i < meas.size(); ++i) {
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(tabList.get(i)),i);
    }

    mTabLayout.invalidate();
    mPagerAdapter.setConfiguration(ct);
    mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

My custom pager adapter is set to know which fragments to show based on the configuration that gets set here.

```
static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private ConfigurationEnum myConfiguration = ConfigurationEnum.DEFAULT;
    private int numPages = 3;

    void setConfiguration(ConfigurationEnum ct) {
        myConfiguration = ct;
        numPages = ct.getTabsToShow().size();
    }

    ConfigurationEnum getConfiguration() {
        return myConfiguration;
    }

    MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(myConfiguration) {
            case CONFIG_A:
                switch(position) {
                    case 0:
                        return FragmentA1.getInstance();
                    case 1:
                        return FragmentA2.getInstance();
                }
                break;
            case CONFIG_B:
                switch(position) {
                    case 0:
                        return FragmentB1.getInstance();
                    case 1:
                        return FragmentB2.getInstance();
                    case 2:
                        return FragmentB3.getInstance();
                    case 3:
                        return FragmentB4.getInstance();
                }
                break;
            case CONFIG_C:
                switch(position) {
                    case 0:
                        return FragmentC1.getInstance();
                    case 1:
                        return FragmentC2.getInstance();
                    case 2:
                        return FragmentC3.getInstance();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numPages;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object obj) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        mCurrentFragment = ((Fragment) object);
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
    }
}
```

And an example implementation of the `ConfigurationEnum`

```
public enum ConfigurationEnum {
    CONFIG_A,
    CONFIG_B,
    CONFIG_C;

    ArrayList<String> getTabsToShow() {
        ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<>();

        switch(this) {
            case CONFIG_A:
                tabs.add("Tab A1");
                tabs.add("Tab A2");
                break;
            case CONFIG_B:
                tabs.add("Tab B1");
                tabs.add("Tab B2");
                tabs.add("Tab B3");
                tabs.add("Tab B4");
                break;
            case CONFIG_C:
                tabs.add("Tab C1");
                tabs.add("Tab C2");
                tabs.add("Tab C3");
                break;
        }

        return tabs;
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m a little lost on your ConfigurationEnum. Is it something you made yourself?

Comment: Yes, that's a custom enum that encapsulates all the information about which tabs to show for a given configuration. You don't have to use an enum, you just have to be able to decide what tabs to show for each user selection somehow. Want me to add code for an example implementation of the enum?

Comment: Yes, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Added an example to the answer and added the missing methods to the FragmentPagerAdapter